# C++, What happens to the stack when its thread reaches its end?

Tags: c++, memory, stack

I am developing a programme that makes use of cryptography, so I find myself working with sensitive data (cipher text, deciphered text, keys, nonce, tags, etc.).

So far all my variables are allocated statically, so using the stack, what I don't want is that when I close the program the memory where my data was allocated (variables, arrays, etc..) is not erased/cleaned.

So what I'm wondering is **after a thread terminates, does its stack, containing all the bytes of my variables, arrays, etc., get cleaned up and then freed?**

**thank you in advance**

Comment: Clean it up yourself. Don't make assumptions of what you cannot control.

Comment: A thread does have its own stack space, but the lifetime of objects/variables is managed by the scope of the function you used on the thread. (Just like the stack of "main()"). What you should NEVER do is kill a thread, just let it run to completion

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Not completely true, the behaviour is pretty well defined. You just need to play by the rules. Just like other parts of C++, lifetime of objects is managed by scope. So using RAII types is recommended (STL containers, std::unique_ptr/std_shared_ptr etc.)

Comment: @PepijnKramer C++ does not bother to specify what happens with an old activation record. I think we are reading OPs Q differently.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, td::unique_ptr/std_shared_ptr ecc.  are used to allocate dynamic memory (in the heap), right?

Comment: Think about wrapping all your sensitive data variables into a class and then, in the destructor for that class, clean up (zero-out) all data. Then, when the scope of a class object ends, its destructor will be called and your clean-up will happen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no guarantee about stack memory being zeroed-out after it's no longer used. But regardless of that, if any of that stack memory is in fact a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, then anything that might theoretically zero-out the stack won't zero-out the other memory. Using things as simple as `std::string` or `std::vector` raise this additional concern. So overall the only way to be sure something gets erased from the memory of a program is to write code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can erase your thread stack by carefully wiping it out at the end.

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <alloca.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

void* runner( void* args ) {
        printf( "Hello World\n" );
        return 0;
}

int main() {
        // allocate stack memory
        size_t pagesize = getpagesize();
        size_t size = 16*pagesize;
        void* addr;
        posix_memalign( &addr, pagesize, size );

        // initialize thread attributes
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init( &attr );
        pthread_attr_setstack( &attr, addr, size );

        // Create and run thread
        pthread_t th;
        pthread_create( &th, &attr, &runner, 0 );
        pthread_attr_destroy( &attr );

        // Wait for it to end
        void* status;
        pthread_join( th, &status );

        // Cleanup stack with a double write
        ::memset( addr, 0, size );
        ::memset( addr, 0xcc, size );
        ::free( addr );
        return 0;
}
```

Note that this is perhaps very system-specific and prone to error. But you do what you gotta do at the end of the day.